# Retain field-content-based union type discrimination on downstream interfaces

Tags: typescript

here's the scenario.

I have an interface representing metadata of a generic `Field` (assume we are talking about `MatFormField` instances from Angular Material) which consist in a name and a type, which is a list of common input types.

```js
export type FieldType = 'string' | 'number' | 'date' | 'datetime' | 'select';

export interface FieldMetadata {
  readonly type: FieldType;
  name: string;
}
```

Some `Field`s are fine with just those metadata, while others need additional info and thus require an interface extension.
I then defined a union type, so I can get right type-hint depending on 'type' field.

```js
// Specific interface for select field
export interface SelectFieldInterface extends FieldMetadata {
  readonly type: 'select';
  options: string[];
}

// All other fields which doesn't need additional info
export interface GenericFieldInterface extends FieldMetadata {
  readonly type: Exclude<FieldType, 'select'>;
}

export type Field = GenericFieldInterface | SelectFieldInterface;

// Understands it's a GenericFieldInterface
const genericField1: Field = {
  type: 'number',
  name: ''
};

const genericField2: Field = {
  type: 'number',
  name: '',
  option: [] // <---- Type Error, unexpected 'options'
};

// Understands it's a SelectFieldInterface
const selectField1: Field = {
  type: 'select',
  name: '',
  options: []
};

const selectField2: Field = {
  type: 'select',
  name: '',
  // <----- Type Error, expected 'options'
};
```

Here everything works as expected (but if you know a better way to manage this, please share).

The problem arise when I want to build upon this abstraction.

Let's say that a new Model should be build atop of this union type in order to keep the discrimination.
I expect something like this to get that result.

```js
export interface Model extends Field {
  additionalProperty: string;
}
```

**BUT** in TypeScript this is not feasible, you cannot extend a union type.
I partially solved this by defining an intermediate "supertype" that accept all properties from all the `Field`s type.

I had to omit type property on specific implementation or problems arise with conflicting accepted type values.

```js
export type ExtendedField = FieldMetadata &
  Partial<Omit<GenericFieldInterface & SelectFieldInterface, 'type'>>;
```

But in this way I lose two things.

The first is discrimination between various implementation.

```js
const genericField: Model = {
  type: 'number',
  name: '',
  additionalProperty: '',
  option: [] // <---- Doesn't fire Type Error for 'option' property, it should
};

const selectField: Model = {
  type: 'select',
  name: '',
  additionalProperty: '',
  // <---- Doesn't fire Type Error for missing 'option' property, it should
};
```

The second is compatibility between `Field` and `Model` signature: I cannot use `Model` where a signature is asking for a `Field`.
Of course **I** know they are compatible, but the compiler doesn't and I'm forced to cast `Model` to `Field` all the times.

```js
function someFn(field: Field) {}

const selectField: Model = {
  type: 'select',
  name: '',
  additionalProperty: '',
  option: []
};

someFn(selectField) <------ Type Error
someFn(selectField as Field) <------ Works with casting
```

Any ideas on how I can better represent these contraints? I tryed to look into Conditional Types but I could not understand if they can be useful to me or not...

Comment: i don't think this is a typescript problem - SOLID principles should help in designing types hierarchy

Comment: Well... To me it seems I followed SOLID principle pretty well, this question itself is an help request to enforce the *L* part of SOLID. But if you have some more specific comments/suggestions I'll be glad to hear them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution to your problem is to use a type alias with an intersection adding the extra properties you need. As long as these types are used just for type checking object literals and don't have to be implemented by classes it should all work fine:

```
type Model = Field & {
    additionalProperty: string;
}
const genericField: Model = {
  type: 'number',
  name: '',
  additionalProperty: '',
  option: [] // err
};

const selectField: Model = { //err
  type: 'select',
  name: '',
  additionalProperty: '',
};
```

Comment: So simple, yet I'd never thought about that.
Ty kind sir, it worked like a charm.